# Extract Dates and compare them from string in Scala

Tags: scala, datetime, jvm

I am trying to extract date from string and compare them. I am new to Scala. The string : `Some(Date: Tue, 14 Aug 2018 20:57:42 GMT)Some(Last-Modified: Tue, 14 Aug 2018 20:57:24 GMT)` I wish to comapare `Date` and `Last Modified`

Comment: does the string contain "Some" and the paren characters?

Comment: Ignore the char sequence "some", that is just something generated by the header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Extract the Dates if working with `Option`**

There are several Scala wrappers for the Java Time API but the example below just uses the Java API directly.

```
val someDate: Option[String] = Some("Date: Tue, 14 Aug 2018 20:57:42 GMT")
val someLastMod: Option[String] = Some("Last-Modified: Tue, 14 Aug 2018 20:57:24 GMT")
```

The we extract the meaningful date substrings ie. we remove the `"Date: "`

```
val dateStr = someDate.get.split("^[\\w\\-]+:")(1).trim
val lastModStr = someLastMod.get.split("^[\\w\\-]+:")(1).trim
```

You should note that the above uses `get()` which assumes you can guarantee you will always have a `Some` and never a `None`. You should read up on working with `Option` in Scala if you don't understand this point.

**Extract the Dates if working with a `String`**

```
val data = "Some(Date: Tue, 14 Aug 2018 20:57:42 GMT)Some(Last-Modified: Tue, 14 Aug 2018 20:57:24 GMT)"
```

First we extract just the string dates we are interested in. The following expression uses `split` to create an array of strings, which we `filter` over to remove any empty strings before finally mapping over whats left and using `take` to remove the trailing parenthesis `)`

```
val dates = data.split("Some\\([\\w\\-]+:*\\s").filter(_.nonEmpty).map(_.take(29))

// dates: Array[String] = Array(Tue, 14 Aug 2018 20:57:42 GMT, Tue, 14 Aug 2018 20:57:24 GMT)
```

Now we extract each date string from the array.

```
val dateStr = dates(0)
val lastModStr = dates(1)
```

**Now use the Java Time API to do comparisons.**

Now we start to use the Java time API. First you need to import the Java packages.

```
import java.time._
import java.time.format._
```

Now create a formatter to match your DateTime pattern in order to convert the `Strings` to `LocalDateTime` instances.

```
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z")    

val date = LocalDateTime.parse(dateStr, formatter)
val lastMod = LocalDateTime.parse(lastModStr, formatter)
```

Do some comparisons using the LocalDateTime API.

```
date.isBefore(lastMod)
date.isAfter(lastMod)
```

Check out the [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) docs for more ways to compare them.

**Consider this**

Will the format for the Dates always be in the same pattern? If not, you will need to think about how you will handle different patterns otherwise you will run into runtime exceptions (`DateTimeParseException`). Read more in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

Comment: Yes, "Some" will always be there, it is added by the header and not in my control. And also yes the dates will always be in the same format, so the regex parsing can be static.

Comment: @Milap, I assumed you were actually referring to the `Some` type from your question. Are you saying that you actually have a string like `Some(Date: Tue, 14 Aug 2018 20:57:42 GMT)`? This is a bit confusing when posting as a Scala question because `Some` is an actual type in Scala.

Comment: it is a part of String, well now you believe I am new to Scala.

Comment: @milap, I added a section to work with the string instead of Options.

Comment: I just replace `.filter(_.nonEmpty).map(_.take(29))` to `.replace(")", "")`, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Are you really trying to parse data that looks like this?

```
val badString = "Some(Date: Tue, 14 Aug 2018 20:57:42 GMT)Some(Last-Modified: Tue, 14 Aug 2018 20:57:24 GMT)"
```

Whoever thought that might be a reasonable way to represent data should go back to school (grade school). But it can be done. First let's try to segregate the data elements we're interested in, and remove some of the cruft along the way.

```
val inArray :Array[String] = badString.split("Some[^:]+: ")
//inArray: Array[String] = Array("", "Tue, 14 Aug 2018 20:57:42 GMT)", "Tue, 14 Aug 2018 20:57:24 GMT)")
```

Next we need to describe the date/time format that we're dealing with. Note that we have to account for a trailing paren `)` in the data.

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
val dtFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z)")
```

Now we can turn all the good data into Java `LocalDateTime` elements. Any `Array` elements that don't match the `DateTimeFormatter` pattern are removed.

```
import util.Try
import java.time.LocalDateTime
val dates :Array[LocalDateTime] = inArray.flatMap{ dateStr =>
  Try(LocalDateTime.parse(dateStr.trim, dtFormatter)).toOption
}
```

So now you can extract the dates, if any, from the `dates` array and compare them using the `LocalDateTime` API.

Comment: Well this data actually comes from the headers in http4s library in scala, legacy code! I know right?

Comment: Because the scala Option[T] type results in Some(value) and the toString rep returns exactly this. LOL about the grade school burn though.